# shorter way to collect many variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function abc(){
var a = 'lorem';
var b = 'ipsum';
//... and so on - abot 20 variables.
// do something with the variables.
}
```

this variables I need in many functions so I tried to create a common function just for give them a value:

```
function givemevars(){
var a = 'lorem';
var b = 'ipsum';
...
}
```

and then

```
function abc(){
givemevers();
console.log(a);
}
```

result: `undefined;`

I know, I should firstly declare all that variables outside any function (like 
 `var a; var b;...`), but the question is - is there any shorter way?

**update**

I also tried:

```
function givemevars(){
a = 'lorem';
}

function abc(){
givemevers();
console.log(a);
}
```

result - `undefined`

```js
function givemevars(){
a = 'lorem';
}

function abc(){
givemevars();
console.log(a);
}

abc();
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a misunderstanding of the scope rules of javascript.  Defining a variable as `var` in a function makes it only available in that function, and in nested functions.

Comment: If you have 20+ variables then you are doing it wrong. Delete everything you have and restructure the code.

Comment: @Taplar, there is no way to change this rule? What if I have 50 variables?

Comment: Scope rules are not something you "change".  It's a constraint of the language you have to learn and code with the understanding of.

Comment: So use an object and pass the reference of the object....

Comment: Why don't you declare and give them value in the `global` scope?

Comment: If you have 20+ variables, there's a really good chance you should be using something like an array or an object.

Comment: @Rahul, because I must twice write all of them - once to declare them outside a function and second - inside each function give them a value

Comment: @puerto that is not accurate.  If you do not give them a `var` when you set them in the method, or if you use `window.variblename = value`, then in both cases they would be global without having to define them first.  However epascarello's suggestion is more OO.  Though, the many different ways being suggested to solve this issue lends itself towards suggesting that this question is too broad.

Comment: @MarkMeyer, array is structured from variables, so again I must declare them firstly and secondly give them a value, that's not shorter way at all

Comment: @puerto, I meant that you can give them value as soon as you declare them. The same thing that you're doing inside `givemevars`, you can do outside.

Comment: @puerto most people don't have the problem you are having, which makes this seem like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You haven't posted enough code for us to know what you are trying to do. Using an object will let you keep the data together and pass it back and forth from a function.

Comment: @Taplar, what? Did you say if I write `a = 'lorem' inside function `a` I will have that value inside function `b`?. without firstly declaring `a` outside a function?

Comment: Yes, if you do `x = y` instead of `var x = y` then `x` will not be scoped only to the function.  http://jsfiddle.net/6p8f9ejn/

Comment: [Just return an object of keys/values](https://jsfiddle.net/pm2cw63y/5/) from the function and assign it to a new variable.

Comment: @Taplar, I tried, just now, it doesn't work, result is `undefined`

Comment: Show us what you tried?  That fiddle clearly shows it works.

Comment: @Taplar, see my update, pls

Comment: @puerto You have a typo in your example (`givemevers();`), but I fixed the typo when i put it in the snippet.  As you can see, it works.

Comment: @Taplar  thanks a lot, that's what I need

Comment: @puerto your updated code has typo and missing method invocation. See I've added an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can re-structure you multiple variables to an `object` and wrap it to a method e.g `giveMeVars()` and just call it using `object.key` notation whenever you need any value from it.

```js
function giveMeVars() {
  const myVars = {
    a: 'lorem',
    b: 'ipsum',
    c: 'zipsum'
    //... and so on - abot 20 variables.
    // do something with the variables.
  }
  return myVars;
}

function abc() {
  let gotVars = giveMeVars();
  console.log(gotVars.a);
}

abc();
```

**Why your existing doesn't work?**

Because it has typo on `givemevars()` and missing method invocation i.e `abc()`. Lets try like this way.

```js
function givemevars() {
  a = 'lorem';
}

function abc() {
  givemevars();
  console.log(a);
}

abc()
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, there are a couple things you need here. 
First is an understanding of [functional scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) in javascript.
This will help you understand why your console.log is undefined;

Second, if you have 20 loose variables you might want to put them inside an object.

```js
let variableContainer = {a:'ipsum', b:'lorum', c: 'whatever'};
variableContainer.d = 'something'; //add new variable or change existing
console.log(variableContainer.a);  //access a
console.log(variableContainer);  //view all
```

Now, you can just pass that object around to get its contents.
you are always going to have to declare all the variables, the question is where?

You can go with your first thought by declaring it outside a function, making a global object (or variable). From there you can call it anywhere in your script (including inside functions).

However, global variables are generally a bad practice. You had some of the right ideas before with you givemevars function. Try something like this:

```js
function doWorkWithVariables(){
  let variableObject = givemevars();
  //now we do work with variables without having to make them global
  console.log('vars', variableObject);
} 

function givemevars(){
  const myVariableObject = {
    a: 'ipsum',
    b:'lorem',
    c:'something'
  }
  return myVariableObject;
}
```